# Multiple methods in single test case

Tags: junit

I am new to Junit. I have a class with four methods. I am creating a test class with test cases. Can I have a test case that uses more than one methods of testing class or there should one test case per one method. What is good practice ?

Comment: Could not get my answer reading this.

Comment: it took you how long, 8-9 minutes to study all the answers over there, along with the links to further reading referred from these answers?

Comment: @gnat: it took me 30 seconds to see that the other question is not a duplicate - it is about the contents of tests, not about their structure.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I have a test case that uses more than one method of the tested class

Obviously yes, how will you otherwise test methods which need a specific initialization before? For example

```
  fooCalculator = new FooCalculator(someParameters);
  fooCalculator.SetOption1(valueForOption1);
  fooCalculator.SetOption2(valueForOption2);
  result = fooCalculator.Calc(); 
  Assert.AreEqual(expectedResultForTheseOptions,result);
```

If, however, your question is "Can I have a test case that **tests** more than one method", then the answer is "you should avoid that", because that will typically result in too large tests. See this [former question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test) for a detailed explanation.